# Why am i getting infinite loop for only thread # 0 after all 5 threads run for multi threading C++ dining philosophers riddle

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix

Now all 5 threads are running. However after 5 threads are run for the first time. Only first thread (thread # 0) runs infinitely blocking rest of the threads.  I only see thread # 0 idle (waiting) and consuming (eating) and again entering into infinite loop other 4 threads do not get a chance after 1st round.

```
struct sem_t_ * sem[5];
struct sem_t_ * lock;

class Phil
{
public:
   Phil()
   {
     isThinking = isEating = 0;
     mId  = 0;
   }

   //~Phil();
   bool isThinking;
   bool isEating;

int mId;

void setID(int id)
{
mId = id;

}

void think()
{
isThinking = 1;
isEating = 0;

cout<<"Thread "<<mId<<" is idle!.\n";


}

void eat()
{

 isThinking = 0;
 isEating = 1;

 cout<<"Thread "<<mId<<" is consuming!.\n";

 }
 };


void pause()
{
Sleep(1000);
}

Phil* pArray = new Phil[5];

void* thread_Create(void*param)
{
int value = 0;
int* id = (int*)param;

for(;;)
{

cout<<"Thread Id = "<<*id<<" running.\n";

pArray[*id].think();

sem_wait(&lock);

int left = *id;
int right = (*id)+1;
if( right > 4) right = 0;

//cout<<"Left = "<<left<<" Right = "<<right<<endl;

sem_getvalue(&sem[left],&value) ;

//cout<<"Left Value = "<<value<<endl;

if( value != 1 )
{
    sem_post(&lock);
    continue;
}

if( value != 1 )
{
    sem_post(&lock);
    continue;
}

sem_wait(&sem[left]);
sem_wait(&sem[right]);

pArray[*id].eat();
sem_post(&sem[left]);
sem_post(&sem[right]);

sem_post(&lock);

pause();
}
return 0;
}

void main(void)
{
int i = 0;

for(i=0; i< 5;i++)
{
pArray[i].setID(i);
sem_init(&sem[i],0,1);

}

sem_init(&lock, 0, 5);

pthread_t threads[5];

for(i=0; i< 5;i++)
{
pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,thread_Create, (void*)&i);
pause();

}

for(i=0; i< 5;i++)
{

pthread_join(threads[i], NULL); //Main thread will block until child threads exit!
}


for(i=0; i< 5;i++)
{
sem_destroy(&sem[i]);
}

sem_destroy(&lock);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this line:

```
pthread_join(threads[i], NULL); //Main thread will block until child threads exit!
```

It is doing exactly what your comment says - your main thread creates one thread (thread 0) and then blocks until thread 0 finishes, which it never does. So your main program never creates any more threads.

The solution is to move the `pthread_join` calls into another loop. i.e. create *all* the threads first, then wait for them all to finish.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However I am still seeing unexpected results.All 5 threads run then only first thread (thread id #0) keep running blocking every other threads. This is my updated code:

Comment: You are passing the address of `i` to every thread. That means every thread gets the same address, so they all think try to work on the same philosopher. Not only that, you main thread reuses`i` and changes it as well. You are better off passing in a pointer to the actual philosopher object that the thread should be working on.